# C# DevExpress GridControl : how to make search according to specific column text

Tags: c#, gridview, filter, devexpress, gridcontrol

[Some sort of list will be displayed when the program runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FToLe.png)

I want to make search with entering text on textedit. When I hit a button the gridview will be refreshed and show that the same values on entered text.

For example:

Firma Adı:ABC(User enters)

- ABC123
- ABCDEF
- .
- .
- .

How can I make filter such that with using `editValueChanged`?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExpress grid offers this functionality out of the box.

You just need to display the AutoFilter row:

- either programmatically using gridView.OptionsView.ShowAutoFilterRow
  property
- or as an end user by right clicking on the columns label area and
  selecting the relevant menu entry

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @GeorgeT's suggesion (which is very good, by the way -- the AutoFilter row is a crowd pleaser), one other thought.

Dev express has a control that does exactly what you appear to be attempting.  It's called the "Find Panel."  You can have it show up at design time from the `OptionsFind` properties of the gridView, and you can also have it show up at runtime via:

```
gridView1.ShowFindPanel();
```

I suspect you will find this is far better than anything you can program by hand...  and with one (or zero) line(s) of code!

[image]

Comment: Of course there is the option of using the Find Panel too, with a difference though. Find Panel marks (or filters) all the columns. The AutoFilter row just filters the current column. Whatever is more suitable..